# How do I use binding with ttkbootstrap.DateEntry to update a Label with the selected date?

Tags: python, tkinter, bind, ttkbootstrap

I'm using the ttkbootstrap framework mainly because of the modern `DateEntry`, and it has some useful themes. My goal is to have a `DateEntry` widget automatically update a `Label` with the date selected from the DatePickerPopup, but the `"<<DateEntrySelected>>"` event using `.bind()` does not work like it does with regular tkinter. My work-around is to use a `Button` to call my update_label function on-click. What is the virtual event that is generated each time the user selects a date?

Here's my code snippet:

```
import ttkbootstrap as ttk
from datetime import datetime


def update_label(event):
    selected_date = cal.entry.get()
    date_object = datetime.strptime(selected_date, "%m/%d/%Y")
    formated_date = date_object.strftime("%A, %b %d")
    label.config(text=f"{formated_date}")


root = ttk.Window()
root.geometry("600x400")

# Label
label = ttk.Label(root, text="Today")
label.pack(pady=5)

# DateEntry
cal = ttk.DateEntry(root, bootstyle="primary")
cal.pack(pady=5)
cal.bind("<<DateEntrySelected>>", update_label)  # FIX

root.mainloop()
```

ttkbootstrap docs: https://ttkbootstrap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/widgets/dateentry/

There, it says... "*A date entry widget combines the Combobox and a Button with a callback attached to the get_date function.
When pressed, a date chooser popup is displayed. The returned value is inserted into the combobox.
The date chooser popup will use the date in the combobox as the date of focus...*"

The workaround is to use a Button, like so...

```
btn = ttk.Button(root, text="Update", command=update_label)
btn.pack(pady=5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `StringVar` and bind it to `calendar.entry`:

```py
from datetime import datetime
from tkinter import StringVar

import ttkbootstrap as ttk


def update_label(sv):
    selected_date = sv.get()
    if selected_date == "":
        return
    date_object = datetime.strptime(selected_date, "%m/%d/%Y")
    formated_date = date_object.strftime("%A, %b %d")
    label.config(text=f"{formated_date}")


root = ttk.Window()
root.geometry("600x400")

# Label
label = ttk.Label(root, text="Today")
label.pack(pady=5)

# DateEntry
cal = ttk.DateEntry(root, bootstyle="primary")
cal.pack(pady=5)

sv = StringVar()
sv.trace("w", lambda name, index, mode, sv=sv: update_label(sv))
cal.entry.configure(textvariable=sv)


root.mainloop()
```

Creates this app:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> My work-around is to use a Button to call my update_label function
> on-click.

The problem can be fix.

Remove the parameter in `update_label` function.

Comment out on line 7 and 8.

Add Button widget.

Snippet:

```
def update_label():
    selected_date = cal.entry.get()
    #date_object = datetime.strptime(selected_date, "%m/%d/%Y")
    #formated_date = date_object.strftime("%A, %b %d")
    label.config(text=f"{selected_date}")

...
...
...
btn = ttk.Button(root, text="Update", command=update_label)
btn.pack(pady=5)
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`ttkbootstrap.DateEntry` does not generate the virtual event `<<DateEntrySelected>>`.  However you can create a custom `DateEntry` class to simulate the feature:

```py
...

class MyDateEntry(ttk.DateEntry):
    # override function 
    def _on_date_ask(self):
        super()._on_date_ask()
        # generate the virtual event
        self.event_generate("<<DateEntrySelected>>")

    # function to return the selected date
    def get_date(self):
        return datetime.strptime(self.entry.get(), self._dateformat)

def update_label(event):
    date_object = event.widget.get_date()
    formated_date = date_object.strftime("%A, %b %d")
    label.config(text=f"{formated_date}")

...

# use the custom DateEntry
cal = MyDateEntry(root, bootstyle="primary")
...
```